# django-generic-views + list index out of range exception when updating object with inline formset

Tags: django, django-generic-views

Thank you guys for your replies. I am still getting the same exception though I changed the code to the following:

```
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
form_class = ProjectForm
template_name = 'projects/project_create.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('projects-list')

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return obj

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    project = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    if self.request.POST:
        context['reward_formset'] = ProjectRewardFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=project)  
    else:
        context['reward_formset'] = ProjectRewardFormSet(instance=project)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    reward_formset = context['reward_formset']
    if reward_formset.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        reward_formset.instance = self.object
        reward_formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Below is the traceback:

```
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
172.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
138.             return self.form_valid(form)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/reztarter/../reztarter/projects/views.py in form_valid
22.         context = self.get_context_data()
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/reztarter/../reztarter/projects/views.py in get_context_data
39.             context['reward_formset'] = ProjectRewardFormSet(self.request.POST)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __init__
697.                                                 queryset=qs, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __init__
424.         super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py in __init__
50.         self._construct_forms()
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py in _construct_forms
115.             self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i))
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in _construct_form
706.         form = super(BaseInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in _construct_form
451.             kwargs['instance'] = self.get_queryset()[i]
...

▶ Local vars
/home/lara/.venv/reztarter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__
190.             return self._result_cache[k]
...

▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, I added the traceback! I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Class-based-views strange. I don't think it is ok to put this logic in the get_context_data method. You should put only the creation of the formset and the most important thing - get_context_data should return context. The validation of the formset should happen in form_valid method.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies! I am still getting the same exception:

Comment: I tried removing the validation to the form_valid function but I still get the same exception, I added the code above!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with InlineFormSets when there are multiple simultaneous edits https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15574.

> It seems that the inline formset code is a bit brittle. An error is thrown when the data submitted in the management form is not in agreement with the state of the database.

Comment: But how can I solve it? I added in the form the following:{{ reward_formset.management_form }} but always same exception

Comment: Fixing this requires changing the internals of InlineFormSet. There is a patch which details the changes needed and how they intend to resolve the problem.

Comment: Where can I find it? I am really stuck on this since days... I would really appreciate if you can give me more details!